# Como acomodar un PDF con iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itextsharp

tengo un problema al acomodar un PDF, soy nuevo con iTextSharp :( quiero alinear en un solo renglón 3 campos pero me los pone como si tuvieran salto de línea.

este es mi método.

```
private void AddEncabezado(ref Document doc, ObtieneInfoRecetasCronicos model)
    {
        Cell cell;
        Style cellStyle = ObtenerCeldaEstiloPDF();
        cellStyle.SetFontSize(10);

        iText.Layout.Element.Table tblDatosEncabezado = new iText.Layout.Element.Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
        tblDatosEncabezado.SetMarginBottom(10);
        tblDatosEncabezado.SetKeepTogether(true);


        cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("Folio de Receta:" + model.FolioReceta));
        tblDatosEncabezado.AddCell(cell.AddStyle(cellStyle));

        cell.Add(new Paragraph("Fecha y hora de expedición:" + model.FechaHoraExpedicion));
        tblDatosEncabezado.AddCell(cell.AddStyle(cellStyle));

        cell.Add(new Paragraph("Número de pre autorización:" + model.NumPreautorizacion));
        tblDatosEncabezado.AddCell(cell.AddStyle(cellStyle));

        doc.Add(tblDatosEncabezado);
    }
```